# Libgdx first person camera controll

Tags: java, camera, libgdx

I just started playing arround with 3D in libgdx. I allready know how to draw basic `Model`s and i tryed to play arround with the `CameraController`. Now i want to create a `FirstPersonCamera` or `FirstPersonCameraController`. I thought about extending `PerspectiveCamera` and adding a `MyMovingObject target` to it. The `MyMovingObject` would hold a `x, y, z position`, where `y` is a constant value, cause i can't move `up/down` at the moment. So my movement is basicly in 2D. The `MyMovingObject` would also store the `left/right rotation`, needed for its `moving direction`/ `xSpeed, zSpeed`. But the `Player` should also be able to look up and down, and this up/down rotation is not really needed for the `MyMovingObject`, as it only changes the view and no other properties. So i am not sure if i go the right way.
I want to be able to go forward, left, right, backward by using `W,A,S,D` and rotate left right by using the mouse. Also i want to look up and down by using the mouse, like in most `First Person` games.
Should i use another way, not creating my own camera by extending `PerspectiveCamera`?
Or is this approach good and i just have to store the up/down rotation in the `MyMovingObject` to, also if it is only needed for the view?
Or would it be better to controll the camera with `W,A,S,D and mouse` and update the `MyMovingObject`s position, depending on cameras position and rotation?
I hope you understand what I mean. It seems a bit complicated to explain it (at least for me).

**EDIT:** I am now using `Vector3 direction`, `Vector3 position` and `Vector3 size` for my NPCs and the player. I calculate the speed by doing: `xSpeed = direction.x / (direction.x + direction.z) * speed;` the same for zSpeed. By doing this i "filter" the y value out of it and i get only the percent of x and y. The only problem is, that when i look straight up `x` and `z` are `0`. I could fix this by using an `UpVecotr`, which gets rotated when i do a "Pitch-rotation". But how do i rotate him? I need to rotate it arround the sideway Vector. Thanks

**EDIT:** The rotation and movement work now (see my answer), but i have really big problems with the limitation of the "Pitch-rotation". I am using: `if (direction.y < 0.9 && angle > 1) doPitchRotation(); else if (direction.y > -0.9 && angle < 1) doPitchRotation();` so if i rotate down and i still look down at least at -0.9 y it just does not perform the rotation. But what really happens: I rotates to - 0.9 then it rotates arround the Y-Axis and at the other side it rotates up, even if i move my mous down. Can you explain why? Why does the Y-Axis flip when i turn arround by looking down?

**EDIT:** It works now. It seems like my upVector got some wrong values sometimes. For landbased cams you can also use crossproduct of Y-Axis and direction Vector. No need for upVector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hey thanks for sharing [this](http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/~stewart/cs583/LearningXNA3_lects/Lect15_Ch11_CreateFirstPersonCamera.html) link. I found it very useful. 
Here's my code on rotating a land based camera and it seems to work without problems.

```
private int mouseX = 0;
private int mouseY = 0;
private float rotSpeed = 0.2f;

@Override
public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
    int magX = Math.abs(mouseX - screenX);
    int magY = Math.abs(mouseY - screenY);

    if (mouseX > screenX) {
        cam.rotate(Vector3.Y, 1 * magX * rotSpeed);
        cam.update();
    }

    if (mouseX < screenX) {
        cam.rotate(Vector3.Y, -1 * magX * rotSpeed);
        cam.update();
    }

    if (mouseY < screenY) {
        if (cam.direction.y > -0.965)
            cam.rotate(cam.direction.cpy().crs(Vector3.Y), -1 * magY * rotSpeed);
        cam.update();
    }

    if (mouseY > screenY) {

        if (cam.direction.y < 0.965)
            cam.rotate(cam.direction.cpy().crs(Vector3.Y), 1 * magY * rotSpeed);
        cam.update();
    }

    mouseX = screenX;
    mouseY = screenY;

    return false;
}
```

This works for landbased cameras. If you want to make a flightcontroll camera, you have to do a pitch rotation arround the `cam.direction.crs(cam.up)`. Instead of using the `Vector3.cpy()` i would store a `Vector3 help`, which gets those temporary values, because `Vector3.cpy()` creates a new `Vector3` and this operation is performed every render loop.
For flightcontroll cameras you also need to add a `roll` rotation and do the `yaw` rotation arround the `cam.up` Vector.

Comment: Nice answer. Just 2 suggestions: 
1) `Vector3.cpy()` seems to create a `new Vector3()` and give it the values of the other Vecotr3. Creating a new Object every render loop is not that good. SO i would use a Vector3 help, which gets the temporary values.
2) For landbased cameras you can also do a pitchrotation arround the direction.crs(Vector3.Y), as much as i understand. Should i edit your answer? I will mark it as accepted then!

Answer (score 3):

[This article](http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/~stewart/cs583/LearningXNA3_lects/Lect15_Ch11_CreateFirstPersonCamera.html) is really helpful in my opinion. I have found a solution which should work, but i haven't tryed it yet. My `MovingObject`s all have a `Vector3 position`, `Vector3 direction`, `Vector3 size` and `Vecotr3 upVector`. The `Player` class extends this `MovingObject` class and adds `Mouse` and `Keycontroll` to the movement.
In the `MovingObject` class i have the moethods:

1. `rotateYaw(float degrees)`: rotates the `Vector3 direction` arround the `Y-Axis` by the given degrees (libgdx has a rotate function for `Vector3`)--> Simple
2. `rotatePitch(float degrees)`: rotates the `Vector3 direction` arround the: `direction.cross(Vector3.Y)`, which is the rotated side Vector of your `MovingObject`, by the given degrees. Also a `Pitch-Rotation` has to rotate the `upVector`, so you rotate the `upVector` arround the same axis, by the given degrees. As soon as you understand this it is simple.
3. `move(delta)` moves your `MovingObject` in `x,z` direction by doing:

   > ```
   > if (direction.y == 1) {
   >   // You are looking straight up, no x,z direction, move in the opposite
   >   // direction of upVector
   >   xSpeed = upVector.x / (Math.abs(upVetor.x) + Math.abs(upVector.z)) * (-speed);
   >   zSpeed = upVector.z / (Math.abs(upVetor.x) + Math.abs(upVector.z)) * (-speed);
   >   position.add(xSpeed * delta, 0, ySpeed * delta);
   > } else if (direction.y == -1) {
   >   // You are looking straight down, no x,z direction, move in the direction of
   >   // upVector
   >   xSpeed = upVector.x / (Math.abs(upVetor.x) + Math.abs(upVector.z)) * speed;
   >   zSpeed = upVector.z / (Math.abs(upVetor.x) + Math.abs(upVector.z)) * speed;
   >   position.add(xSpeed * delta, 0, ySpeed * delta);
   > } else {
   >   // You are not looking straight up or down, so you have x,z direction. Use
   >   // that.
   >   xSpeed = direction.x / (Math.abs(direction.x) + Math.abs(direction.z)) * speed;
   >   zSpeed = direction.z / (Math.abs(direction.x) + Math.abs(direction.z)) * speed;
   >   position.add(xSpeed * delta, 0, ySpeed * delta);
   > }
   > ```

I did not test this until now, but i think it should work. Note, that in the `Pitch-rotation` you should also limit it to straight up/ straight down. Do this by checking the signum of x and z. If they change while you are doing a `Pitch-rotation` you rotated over 90 degrees.
I am stil waiting for other answers and if i am wrong please correct me!

**EDIT:** I tested it. It works like this, but there are a few things to take care of:

1. `direction.cross(upVector)` changes the `direction` Vector. So store that data somewhere first! After using it reset the direction Vector.
2. The Pitch limitation has a problem: If you controll signum change, as i suggested the following happens: you look straight up, signum x and signum z are 0. You look down, signum changes and your action (limiting) starts. So take care that you also check, if it is not zero.
   I stil don't know how to do the pitch limitation and i edit my question to explain my issue.
3. Think about normalizing your `direction` and `upVector` whenever you change something!

I think this should work pretty good. If you have any improvements let me know and i will update this here. If you have another solution please add an answer! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I know that this question already has good answers. But I had some issues with the selected answer. And I just want to help someone who is looking for the same solution. 
I noticed some strange behaviour with the selected answer. I doesn't keep the Y exis as up. Which is of course very important on a fps. So this one is not perfect but I wanted to put this here.

```
// put into the create() method.
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputProcessor() {
        private int dragX, dragY;
        float rotateSpeed = 0.2f;
        // dont' forget to override other methods.
        @Override
        public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
            Vector3 direction = cam.direction.cpy();

            // rotating on the y axis
            float x = dragX -screenX;
            // change this Vector3.y with cam.up if you have a dynamic up.
            cam.rotate(Vector3.Y,x * rotateSpeed);

            // rotating on the x and z axis is different
            float y = (float) Math.sin( (double)(dragY -screenY)/180f);
            if (Math.abs(cam.direction.y + y * (rotateSpeed*5.0f))< 0.9) {
                cam.direction.y +=  y * (rotateSpeed*5.0f) ;
            }

            cam.update();
            dragX = screenX;
            dragY = screenY;
            return true;
        }

    });
```

NOTE: Don't use any camera controllers.
NOTE2: This might come handy: `Gdx.input.setCursorCatched(true);`

EDIT: I just wanted to share the walking function I use to change position of the camera with wasd keys. When `W` key is down the `forward` is true. And when the key is up `forward` is false. Other directions have the same principle. To detect the key down and up, please use the `InputProcessor` in the above code.
This creates movement in the two dimensional space (X-Z axises). The direction of the camera will not change the direction of the movement as we are eliminating the Y axis. of the direction.
One must now even if camera is directed to the sky (at a non 90 degree angle with the ground), the length of the direction vector is not fixed to `1.0f`. So there will not be any loss of movement speed.
To test this I rotated camera up and down (moved the mouse forward and backward) and the x and z values of the direction vector didn't change. So when the y axis of the direction vector is eliminated, we have a 2d direction vector which doesn't effected by the Y angle of the camera.

```
private void walking(float timeElapsed) {
        float speed = movementSpeed;
        if ((forward | back) & (right | left)) {
            speed /= Math.sqrt(2);
        }
        System.out.println(speed);
        if (forward) {
            Vector3 v = cam.direction.cpy();
            v.y = 0f;
            v.x *= speed * timeElapsed;
            v.z *= speed * timeElapsed;
            cam.translate(v);
            cam.update();
        }
        if (back) {
            Vector3 v = cam.direction.cpy();
            v.y = 0f;
            v.x = -v.x;
            v.z = -v.z;
            v.x *= speed * timeElapsed;
            v.z *= speed * timeElapsed;
            cam.translate(v);
            cam.update();
        }
        if (left) {
            Vector3 v = cam.direction.cpy();
            v.y = 0f;
            v.rotate(Vector3.Y, 90);
            v.x *= speed * timeElapsed;
            v.z *= speed * timeElapsed;
            cam.translate(v);
            cam.update();
        }
        if (right) {
            Vector3 v = cam.direction.cpy();
            v.y = 0f;
            v.rotate(Vector3.Y, -90);
            v.x *= speed * timeElapsed;
            v.z *= speed * timeElapsed;
            cam.translate(v);
            cam.update();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thansk for the answer. But i guess the Up-Axis shouldn't be the same as the y-axis. Think about this: You look straight up. That means, your direction-vector, your up-vector and the y-axis are all the same. How can you know where to move, when pressing forward? Therefore i rotate the up-vector too, when making a `pitch-rotation` and use the y-axis for `yaw-rotation`. So when i look straight up, the up-vector is pointing behind me, so iknow where to move when pressing forward.

Comment: but what if you look straight up? v.x and v.y would be 0, wouldn't they? Then you have no speed at all right?

Comment: @Springrbua HI there. I understand you didn't want pitch and yaw. Classic shooters don't have that (like cs). and I tried the selected answer and it had unexpected pitch and yawn occurances. So I wrote this. Sole purpose of this method is it doesn't let pitch, twist etc.

Comment: @Springrbua it doesn't let you look 90 degree up (only 81 degrees). Also you cannot look directly up. Then the camera would be upside down if you  go too far.

Comment: @Springrbua And if you want to pitch, camera could be rotated around the direction vector. I didn't test this.

Comment: Okay, if you limit the pitch rotation to < 90°, then it should be fine. Thanks for thhis answer, i guess it could help someone in future. +1