# Math behind a 3rd person camera

Tags: java, 3d, camera, libgdx

I have been trying for quite some time now and I cant seem to find anything about 3rd person cameras. I just want to make a simple 3rd person camera but it gets difficult because I'm in 3d. So far I can do the camera on 1 plane but after that its messed up. I'm using libgdx with ModelInstances if anyone knows libgdx.

I don't need you to hand me the code for it, I just need help on how to write this out with the information I have. I know the velocity in x y and z, the rotation in x y z of the object, and its position in x y z. I can make the camera look at the object so all I have to do is position it behind and above it no matter what the orientation is for the object. Any links or explanations are greatly appreciated :)

---

**Solution:**
Xoppa posted in the comments a link to his chaseCam that extends perspective cam and It is amazing. Since it wasn't an answer I could mark it as accepted but it did what I needed. Heres the link [chaseCamera.java](https://github.com/xoppa/world/blob/master/src/com/xoppa/android/world/ChaseCamera.java) All credit to Xoppa for the answer, just making it easier to find.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish by making a 3rd person camera.  Are you trying to create an image based on the position, look-at, and up orientation of the camera?

Comment: Im in a 3D world, trying to position the camera behind my 'player' object, I can't get the camera to follow the object

Comment: just realized title said 3D camera. meant to be 3rd person camera

Comment: I suspect you need to specify the look-at value of the camera which should be the position of the player. The camera's position is a constant offset of that position.  Thats the best I can suggest without diving into the libgdx library.

Comment: @Mike I dont need you to go into the library, I can do `camera.lookAt(pos)` and that takes care of the angle it looks at, I can get the offset to work. i.e 2 units behind, 1 up

Comment: Do you know how to use the mouse to move arround the camera? If yes then you can simply move the camera to the right, in your mouse moved method, when you move the mouse to the left (thats the normal behaivor for 3rd person cameras). You know where to move it, by using the cameras direction vector. Here some more infos (its a first person cam but could help): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21825959/libgdx-first-person-camera-controll

Comment: Perhaps this helps: https://github.com/xoppa/world/blob/master/src/com/xoppa/android/world/ChaseCamera.java

Comment: @Xoppa what version of libgdx was that compiled with? the Vector3.mul doesn't seem to exist anymore

Comment: Vector3.mul is replaced by Vector3.scl

Comment: @xoppa yea I found that and updated it, just forgot to say something.. It works mostly now, I'm going to play around with it a little more because it doesn't seem to rotate around the object.. but its a great place to start. Love your 3d tutorial btw :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do on each frame after updating the player's position:

```
camera.up.set(0,1,0); //Not sure if this is necessary. 
                      //Making sure up is always up after 
                      //last frame's lookAt() call.
camera.postion.set(player.position)
    .add(-UNITS_BACK, UNITS_UP, 0)
    .rotate(Vector3.UP, player.angle);
camera.lookAt(player.position);
camera.update();
```

where `player.angle` is the number of degrees counter-clockwise the player is facing from the X-axis.

That's a simple starting point. You'll probably want to smooth out the movement by limiting the speed at which the camera can move or giving it a second order interpolated movement to this target position and direction.